# R studio is not recognising the date cells that were uploaded from google sheets

Tags: r

I have uploaded Historical timeseries data in OHLC format in to R from Googlsheets.There are 5 columns that contain "numeric" and one column which has data in "date" format.The data that are"numeric" are correctly read by R while the date column has not been recognised.How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you say more what "has not been recognized" means here? What is the source data, what code and packages are you using to access it, what warnings or errors or unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: Hi Ramesh! Can you include more debugging information. E.g. run dput on the dataframe with the relevant columns, and paste it in. Include any relevant code etc.

Comment: @Jon Spring:The cells that are formatted as "Date" in GS has not been captured by R Studio.The cells in the column "date" are blank. This is how R displays the downloaded data::1 <dttm [1]>  6862  6943  6814  6937 2167000

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is how the cells in Date column has been displayed in R.  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-05-06"
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-02-06"
  ..$ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-01-06"
  ..$ : chr "05/31/2023"
  ..$ : chr "05/30/2023"
  ..$ : chr "05/29/2023"
  ..$ : chr "05/26/2023".....As seen this is a mixture of different formats.GS does not allow format cleaning. This is the biggest challenge. Thoughts??